# MVC nested child actions and models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MapController with a single Index action  taking a MapViewModel parameter.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Index(MapViewModel mapViewModel)
```

From a normal page controller everything works as expected when I call it:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Map", new { Longitude = Model.Rally.Longitude.GetValueOrDefault(), Latitude = Model.Rally.Latitude.GetValueOrDefault(), LegendConfiguration = legend })
```

However if I call this from within another child action, I always receive the error

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '...', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'MapViewModel'

When calling my Map controllers Index action from within the view of another child action, it always passes the child actions model, not the specific model I've set.

Is that expected behaviour?

Comment: Show your View code where exception occures. And code of this View ViewModel

Comment: Why? The view code for the child action has the Html.Action call in it you can see above. the MapViewModel is just a POCO.